# IBM DB2 v9.5 requires admin rights to run every time?

Tags: database, db2, database-administration, db2-luw

How can we install IBM DB2 v9.5 express edition database so that we can access DB2 directly **without admin rights**?

(Please note I want to access **without** admin rights)

Thanks

Comment: DB2 9.5 is out of support and I would recommend using a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

You can install DB2 in either as root or non-root. The latter would mean installing DB2 without system admin privileges.

Once DB2 is installed, you need to grant other users `connect` privilege and possibly some other privileges (create new schemas, new tables, insert data, optimize the database, ...?). Those users could connect to DB2 and would not have admin privileges.

There are more options available, but adding non-privileged users is probably what you want to do.

Note that DB2 9.5 is out of support and not recommended.

Comment: thanks for reply.
DB2 is installed by admin user; and later if non-admin user wants to connect to DB2, how can one grant connect privilege to this non-admin user on the same PC?

Comment: The admin has to do that. See here http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000958.html

Comment: Before giving grant, non-admin users used to get 9505 error.

When I executed following command:
 GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE TO USER <user_name>;
non-admin users are not getting 9505 error but DB2 launches momentarily and then gets closed on its own. What could be the reason?

(Please note I should not add these non-admin users as "administrator" users in Windows-7)

Comment: Henrik, could you please help me out with query posted in above comment?

Comment: I don't have a v9.5 available, only v11, and not on Windows. The users don't need to be admin users, there are different options to it. The key is to grant them database connect privilege and then access privileges to tables etc.